# Can anyone help me to get valgrind work on Mavericks?

Tags: valgrind, osx-mavericks

The latest version of valgrind available is 3.9.0 which supports Mac OS X 10.7. I have Mac OS X 10.9.2. I've just begun learning C programming and I need valgrind before I go any further. 
Had anyone successfully ran valgrind on Mavericks??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any alternatives to valgrind on Mac OS X Mountain Lion and Mavericks to detect memory leaks for C/C++ applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719762/are-there-any-alternatives-to-valgrind-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-and-mavericks-t)

Answer (score 0):

Check here for the work of Frederic Germain: 
https://bugs.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=85889&action=edit