# "Incorrect checksum for freed object" in library's destructors

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do some measurements on sections of an audio signal (read as a `std::vector<double>`) which involves some signal-processing using [Aquila](http://aquila-dsp.org/). I'm calculating the MFCC constants using the same functions as in [their example](https://github.com/zsiciarz/aquila/blob/master/examples/mfcc_calculation/mfcc_calculation.cpp), but instead of an `Aquila::SineGenerator` I'm creating an `Aquila::SignalSource` from the vector, [using this constructor](https://github.com/zsiciarz/aquila/blob/master/aquila/source/SignalSource.h#L85).

My function, with irrelevant code removed, is:

```
void measure(std::vector<double> &output_vector, std::vector<double> &audio, int start_index, int end_index) {
    // Copy the raw note over.
    std::vector<double> note_audio(end_index - start_index);
    std::copy(audio.begin() + start_index, audio.begin() + end_index, note_audio.begin());

    // Calculate the MFCC constants.
    Aquila::SignalSource input(note_audio, 44100);
    Aquila::Mfcc mfcc(input.getSamplesCount());
    auto mfccValues = mfcc.calculate(input);

    // Copy them over to the output vector.
    for (int i = 0; i < mfccValues.size(); i++) {
        output_vector.push_back(mfccValues[i]);
    }
}
```

When this is run - often, but not always, the second or third time it's called - it crashes and outputs:

```
prog(15384,0x7fff7cafb310) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f8781863208: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

So, I fire up lldb and debug, setting a breakpoint at `malloc_error_break`, and get this stacktrace:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x23c194, 0x00007fff8f487bc0 libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc_error_break, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.2
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff8f487bc0 libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc_error_break
    frame #1: 0x00007fff8f4815c7 libsystem_malloc.dylib`szone_error + 386
    frame #2: 0x00007fff8f482e1a libsystem_malloc.dylib`small_free_list_remove_ptr + 291
    frame #3: 0x00007fff8f47f737 libsystem_malloc.dylib`szone_free_definite_size + 3429
    frame #4: 0x00000001000029a5 prog-debug`std::__1::__vector_base<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >::~__vector_base() [inlined] std::__1::__deallocate(__ptr=0x00000001008f3800) + 421 at new:164
    frame #5: 0x000000010000299c prog-debug`std::__1::__vector_base<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >::~__vector_base() [inlined] std::__1::allocator<double>::deallocate(this=0x0000000100307888, __p=0x00000001008f3800, (null)=6300) + 8 at memory:1636
    frame #6: 0x0000000100002994 prog-debug`std::__1::__vector_base<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >::~__vector_base() [inlined] std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<double> >::deallocate(__a=0x0000000100307888, __p=0x00000001008f3800, __n=6300) + 24 at memory:1447
    frame #7: 0x000000010000297c prog-debug`std::__1::__vector_base<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >::~__vector_base(this=0x0000000100307878) + 380 at vector:476
    frame #8: 0x0000000100002e25 prog-debug`std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >::~vector(this=0x0000000100307878) + 21 at vector:481
    frame #9: 0x0000000100002355 prog-debug`std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >::~vector(this=0x0000000100307878) + 21 at vector:481
    frame #10: 0x000000010004b99c prog-debug`Aquila::MelFilter::~MelFilter() + 28
    frame #11: 0x000000010004b975 prog-debug`Aquila::MelFilter::~MelFilter() + 21
    frame #12: 0x000000010004b8b7 prog-debug`std::__1::__vector_base<Aquila::MelFilter, std::__1::allocator<Aquila::MelFilter> >::~__vector_base() + 279
    frame #13: 0x000000010004b795 prog-debug`std::__1::vector<Aquila::MelFilter, std::__1::allocator<Aquila::MelFilter> >::~vector() + 21
    frame #14: 0x000000010004b775 prog-debug`std::__1::vector<Aquila::MelFilter, std::__1::allocator<Aquila::MelFilter> >::~vector() + 21
    frame #15: 0x000000010004b755 prog-debug`Aquila::MelFilterBank::~MelFilterBank() + 21
    frame #16: 0x000000010004b545 prog-debug`Aquila::MelFilterBank::~MelFilterBank() + 21
    frame #17: 0x000000010004b463 prog-debug`Aquila::Mfcc::calculate(Aquila::SignalSource const&, unsigned long) + 323
    frame #18: 0x00000001000203b6 prog-debug`measure(the_vector=0x00007fff5fbfd8c8, audio=0x00007fff5fbfe478, start_index=7078, end_index=13378) + 1270 at measureVector.cpp:62
    frame #19: 0x0000000100018eb2 prog-debug`extractVectors(vectors=0x00007fff5fbfe4e0, audio=vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > at 0x00007fff5fbfe478, sample_rate=44100, bg_audio=vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > at 0x00007fff5fbfe460, bg_sample_rate=44100, notes=0x00007fff5fbfe490) + 3234 at extractVectors.cpp:74
    frame #20: 0x000000010002b915 prog-debug`train(results=0x00007fff5fbff620, training_path=std::__1::string at 0x00007fff5fbff608, bg_audio=vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > at 0x00007fff5fbff5f0, bg_sample_rate=44100, classes=0x00007fff5fbff638) + 5733 at train.cpp:44
    frame #21: 0x00000001000211d3 prog-debug`MUSE(input_path=std::__1::string at 0x00007fff5fbff948, training_path=std::__1::string at 0x00007fff5fbff930, noise_profile_path=std::__1::string at 0x00007fff5fbff908, output_path=std::__1::string at 0x00007fff5fbff8f0) + 995 at muse.cpp:44
    frame #22: 0x00000001000217fd prog-debug`main(argc=5, argv=0x00007fff5fbffab8) + 717 at muse.cpp:55
```

Sometimes I get that, sometimes I get other errors in the internals ([you can see them here](https://gist.github.com/cnvandev)), but they all start at `Aquila::Mfcc::calculate()` and usually seem to involve a destructor. I've run into errors which look similar and are due to trying to return stack-based variables (oops - it's why I'm passing in my output_vector and modifying it in the function), but I don't see that here - I'm using it, then copying over the `double` values to my output vector. I've tried creating `note_audio` as a pointer with `new`, I've tried creating it as an array instead of `std::vector` both on the stack and on the heap, to no avail.

Building C++11 on OS X Mavericks, using CMake and LLVM. As per suggestion in the comments, I've saved a Gist of [the first ~300 lines of a Valgrind output](https://gist.github.com/cnvandev/8c47a1c42527bc7dc32f) (although it keeps going until >100 errors). What am I missing here?

Comment: Tip: you can simply write `std::vector<double> note_audio(audio.begin() + start_index, audio.begin() + end_index);` and not need to do the copy, nor all those default-constructions.

Comment: What platform, compiler, etc are you using. Is valgrind available on your system?  If so, run it to get detailed information about misuse of memory.

Comment: @DaleWilson: Rookie mistake, sorry! Building C++11 on OS X Mavericks, using CMake and LLVM, I've heard Valgrind isn't working on Mavericks (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719762/are-there-any-alternatives-to-valgrind-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-and-mavericks-t) but maybe it is? (http://calvinx.com/2014/05/04/valgrind-on-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks/). I'll see if I can get it working and report back.

Comment: @DaleWilson: I ran Valgrind and got a very long output, looks like there are a bunch of errors (although I'm not sure how to interpret them). The first 300-or-so lines are at this gist https://gist.github.com/cnvandev/8c47a1c42527bc7dc32f. I know `Address 0xa4a050 is 0 bytes after a block of size 25,200 alloc'd` usually refers to a write at position 25,201 on a 25,200-length vector, but I'm not sure where I'm specifying the wrong length.

Comment: Possibly your indices are out of bounds of the input vector?

Comment: I would suggest running this on valgrind on Linux, for more reliable output. It will most likely be very loud when things start to go wrong.

Comment: Also, std::copy copies [first, last)

Comment: The stack trace that valgrind produced for you says you are in Aquila::Mfcc::calculate(...) called from measureVector(...), accessing a vector that was allocated by Aquila in a call from measureVector() to getFft().  Check the arguments to getFft() and calculate().

Comment: Checked indices on input vector, it's not out of bounds there. For example, on a vector of length 908800, it's crashing on [7078,  13378] (and sporadically - another run that section works but the next, [23281, 30852], doesn't). The `Aquila::SignalSource` is also the same size as the input vector...it's possible the bug is in its copy constructor.

(I've also updated the constructor to use @KerrekSB's suggestion of `std::vector<double> note_audio(audio.begin() + start_index, audio.begin() + end_index);`. I'll try Valgrind on Linux, though, maybe it'll be more helpful.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this SO question to the Aquila GitHub Issues page and [got back an answer](https://github.com/zsiciarz/aquila/issues/34#issuecomment-50204624) from the library's creator. [Credit goes to another issue](https://github.com/zsiciarz/aquila/issues/35) for the discovery (good timing).

In short: OouraFFT, the FFT library used by Aquila, requires a vector size that is a power of 2, but doesn't complain if that's not the case, it just writes to deallocated memory on the first call to `OouraFFT::fft()`. The take-away lesson is to always assert conditions you need to check before going crazy on a heap.