# Crash with circular linked list

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implemented a linked list (i believe this is a circular linked list) but upon using it, it eventually crashes. I think this is because the traversal pointer i use is not set properly to 0, and eventually dereferenced and exhibiting undefined behaviour.

I would appreciate your help.

This is the function i am using:

```
struct records t_head = 0;

struct records* find_id(Rect a)
{

    struct records* tmp;
    struct records* prev;

    // Add first node
    if (t_head == NULL) {
        tmp = new records;
        tmp->b = a;
        tmp->id = trecord_count + 1;
        tmp->tally.resize(labelsInfo.size());
        tmp->frames = 0;
        t_head = tmp;
        t_head->next = NULL;
        trecord_count++;
    }

    else {
        // Check if there is any node that has delete_flag set first
        tmp = t_head;
        while (tmp) {

            if (delete_flag) {

                // Delete here
                if (tmp == t_head) {
                    t_head = tmp->next;
                    delete (tmp);
                    trecord_count--;
                }
                else {
                    prev->next = tmp->next;
                    delete (tmp);
                    trecord_count--;
                }
            }

            prev = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }

        tmp = new records;
        tmp->b = a;
        tmp->id = trecord_count + 1;
        tmp->tally.resize(labelsInfo.size());
        tmp->frames = 0;
        tmp->next = t_head;
        t_head = tmp;
        trecord_count++;
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

Struct definition is:

```
struct records {
int id;
Rect b;
vector<int> tally= {};
int frames=0;
int delete_flag=0;
struct records *next;
};
```

Comment: Can you post more complete code? This else out of nowhere?

Comment: This is tagged C, but you're using `new` and `delete`; are you sure you aren't using a C++ compiler?

Comment: @Haldean Sorry, it's old c code but i'm going to convert it to C++ syntax.

Comment: @koper i can post the main function if that helps? Otherwise there might be to much code so i thought i keep it down to a relevant snippet.

Comment: @poonam Proper indentation also helps

Comment: Hi qxz - yes you are right, i will have to review that. I wish i could blame the website for messing up my format but the indentation needs some work as well :-)

Comment: What is the `records` struct definition? Also, on what line does it crash? Have you stepped through with a debugger?

Comment: Why do you want implement linked list in C++? You should do it when you code in C. I don't understand why you migrate your code. This doesn't make cense.

Comment: Yeah, if you want a linked list in C++, you should use the standard library `std::list`

Comment: You need to give us the minimum code necessary to replicate the problem. That means we should be able to compile and run it and thereby duplicate the problem. But you should remove as much code as you possibly can. (You may find that you solve the problem yourself in the process of preparing this.)

Comment: I added it to the question. I'll have to run it through a debugger.

Comment: Unless this is an academic exercise to learn more about coding this is a complete waste of time. The C++ Standard Library has a wide variety of containers, including those that operate like linked lists. Why are you using a `struct` in C++? This should be a `class`. It should have an initializer to properly populate things like `next`. It should have tests.

Comment: What prevents `prev` from pointing to memory that was deleted when `tmp != t_head`? Looking through the code, that appears to be possible because you `delete tmp` and then assign the thing you just deleted to `prev`.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Ah, sorry, just read your last comment after I wrote my answer. The answer includes a correction for this flaw in the code.  `valgrind` shows this problem right away.

Comment: Thanks, i wish i could use valgrind, i'm on a mac. It's a academic exercise really, but yes i guess i should use std::list, that seems a lot easier (but i'd still like to know how it works!).

Comment: There is some information about valgrind on Mac there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719762/are-there-any-alternatives-to-valgrind-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-and-mavericks-t

Comment: [Dr. Memory](http://www.drmemory.org/docs/page_install_macos.html) should also work on Mac (depending on the version of your OS).

Answer (score 0):

The following code runs but it also shows flaws beside of these already mentioned in the comments.

1. In your version you access the pointer in `tmp` which you just deleted in the loop for searching records with set `delete_flag`. This is corrected in the version below. The required modifications are marked with `//< Tobias`. Note, that you find such errors easily with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) under linux. Andon M. Coleman also mentions this [in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029135/crash-with-circular-linked-list/41030112#comment69267135_41029135).
2. In your version of `find_id` there is actually no search for `a` implemented. I've implemented such a search in my version.
3. If you delete some record in the middle of the list the end record keeps its id but you decrement `trecord_count` and assign the same id once again. So you end up with multiple records with the same id.

**EDIT:** I added some logging to the program. Maybe, that helps you to see what is going on. Furthermore, I misuse `frames` as a real `id`. I.e., no two records have the same `frames`-value. The records are in braces the full list is in square brackets. And **NO** you do not have a circular list. Maybe, you get the wrong impression because you are adding new records at the front and therefore, you need to use the old value of `t_head` as value for the `next`-pointer of the newly created record.

The output of the program is:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g -O0 ./test.cc -o a.exe && ./a.exe
Returning { frames=1 id=1 b=1 }
Full content:
[ { frames=1 id=1 b=1 } ]

Adding { frames=2 id=2 b=2 }
Returning { frames=2 id=2 b=2 }
Full content:
[ { frames=2 id=2 b=2 }, { frames=1 id=1 b=1 } ]

Adding { frames=3 id=3 b=3 }
Returning { frames=3 id=3 b=3 }
Full content:
[ { frames=3 id=3 b=3 }, { frames=2 id=2 b=2 }, { frames=1 id=1 b=1 } ]

Deleting head { frames=3 id=3 b=3 }
Adding { frames=4 id=3 b=4 }
Returning { frames=4 id=3 b=4 }
Full content:
[ { frames=4 id=3 b=4 }, { frames=2 id=2 b=2 }, { frames=1 id=1 b=1 } ]

Returning { frames=2 id=2 b=2 }
Full content:
[ { frames=4 id=3 b=4 }, { frames=2 id=2 b=2 }, { frames=1 id=1 b=1 } ]

Deleting { frames=2 id=2 b=2 }
Adding { frames=5 id=3 b=5 }
Returning { frames=5 id=3 b=5 }
Full content:
[ { frames=5 id=3 b=5 }, { frames=4 id=3 b=4 }, { frames=1 id=1 b=1 } ]


At exit: [ { frames=5 id=3 b=5 }, { frames=4 id=3 b=4 }, { frames=1 id=1 b=1 } ]
```

There follows the program named `test.cc`:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

typedef int Rect;

struct records {
    int id;
    Rect b;
    std::vector<int> tally= {};
    int frames=0;
    int delete_flag=0;
    struct records *next;
};

struct records *t_head = 0;
int trecord_count = 0;
int trecord_frames = 0;

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const records& r) {
    os << "{ frames=" << r.frames << " id=" << r.id << " b=" << r.b << " }";
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const records* r) {
    os << "[ ";
    if(r)
        os << *r;
    for(r=r->next; r; r=r->next)
        std::cout << ", " << *r;
    std::cout << " ]\n";
}

struct records* find_id(Rect a)
{

    struct records* tmp;
    struct records* prev;

    // Add first node
    if (t_head == NULL) {
        tmp = new records;
        tmp->b = a;
        tmp->id = trecord_count + 1;
        tmp->tally.resize(0);
        tmp->frames = ++trecord_frames;
        t_head = tmp;
        t_head->next = NULL;
        trecord_count++;
    }

    else {
        // Check if there is any node that has delete_flag set first
        tmp = t_head;
        while (tmp) {

            if (tmp->delete_flag) {

                // Delete here
                if (tmp == t_head) {
                    std::cout << "Deleting head " << *tmp << std::endl;
                    t_head = tmp->next;
                    delete (tmp);
                    trecord_count--;
                    tmp = t_head; //< Tobias
                }
                else {
                    std::cout << "Deleting " << *tmp << std::endl;
                    prev->next = tmp->next;
                    delete (tmp);
                    trecord_count--;
                    tmp = prev->next; //< Tobias
                }
            } else {
                prev = tmp;
                tmp = tmp->next;
            }
        }

        // Search for the id
        tmp = t_head;
        while(tmp && (tmp->b != a))
            tmp = tmp->next;

        if(!tmp) {
            tmp = new records;
            tmp->b = a;
            tmp->id = trecord_count + 1;
            tmp->tally.resize(0);
            tmp->frames = ++trecord_frames;
            tmp->next = t_head;
            t_head = tmp;
            std::cout << "Adding " << *tmp << std::endl;
            trecord_count++;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Returning " << *tmp << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Full content:\n" << t_head << std::endl;

    return tmp;
}

int main() {
    find_id(1);
    find_id(2);
    find_id(3);

    t_head->delete_flag=1;
    find_id(4);

    records* r = find_id(2);
    r->delete_flag = 1;
    find_id(5);

    std::cout << "\nAt exit: " << t_head;

    return 0;
}

/*
    Local Variables:
    compile-command: "g++ -std=c++11 -g -O0 ./test.cc -o a.exe && ./a.exe"
    End:
*/
```

Comment: Many thanks Tobias (and others), i'll have a good look through this. I think i've seen the same behaviour with 3, could you tell me why it keeps the same id? Am i not deleting that record?

Comment: @poonam See my edit. You are deleting in the middle of the list and therefore you do not delete the head which was added last and therefore has the last value of `trecord_count`. `trecord_count` is decremented at deletion of records and therefore the old value is used again.